# accessing variables/functions from subclass in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I am having a problem with accessing public variable 'activity', which is a `UIActivityIndicatorView` type, see class declaration below in `QuickStartViewController.h`:

```
@interface QuickStartViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate> {
@public
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;

@end
```

The function is called from another class:

```
#import "QuickStartViewController.h"
@interface NumberValidator : QuickStartViewController....
```

See below:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[activity startAnimating];
NSLog(@"This function is called, but [activity startAnimating] still doesn't work...");
}
```

Note: `[activity startAnimating]` works fine when called within the `QuickStartViewController` class.

**Do you have any suggestions as to why `[activity startAnimating]` is not working?**

Answer (score 1):

The `IBOutlet` macro indicates that the `UIActivityIndicatorView` will be constructed and assigned when an instance of `QuickStartViewController` or `NumberValidator` are instantiated via NSBundle's `+loadNibNamed:owner:options:` or calling UIViewController's `initWithNibName:bundle:`

If you are not instantiating your `NumberValidator` via it's nib, then the activity property will not be assigned.  If you are constructing it via a nib, then you have not assigned the outlet with an appropriate `UIActivityIndicatorView` in Interface Builder, by CTRL+Dragging your `UIActivityIndicatorView` to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by setting a breakpoint in -connectionDidFinishLoading: and verifying that activity is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

This probably works - i.e. the activity indicator starts animating.  There may be another problem, though - the GUI is not refreshed until you stop processing the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, and therefore it *seems* that `[activity startAnimating]` doesn't work. (You can test this by not calling [activity stopAnimating] - it should show up eventually.)

See e.g. [this thread (connectionDidFinishLoading - how to force update UIView?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994495/connectiondidfinishloading-how-to-force-update-uiview/) and [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994495/connectiondidfinishloading-how-to-force-update-uiview/2026094#2026094).

Comment: Hi adam,

I have tried this - with no luck :(

Kind regards,

Mitul

Answer (score 0):

Is it (a) not compiling, (b) crashing when it hits there, or (c) just not doing anything? My suspicion is that it's (c), and it's because you don't have an activity indicator there. Try logging the value of activity to the console, and verify its a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses.

The connectionDidFinishLoading does successfully execute, and I have placed NSLogs to confirm. However, the startAnimating doesn't.

Note:

If I do [activity startAnimating]; within the following then it works...:

**QuickStartViewController.m (not NumberValidator.m)**:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {
[activity startAnimating];
...
}
```

Comment: Is `activity` nil in the `connectionDidFinishLoading`? Have you tested my suggestion to not turn it off and wait if it appears when you finish processing the URL response?