# Cocoa Touch ProgressView in Loop not displaying update

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiprogressview

If I have an innocuous loop that gets fired off when I press a button like:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    calculatingProgressBar.progress = 0.0;  
    int j = 1000;
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        calculatingProgressBar.progress = (i/j);
    }
}
```

The ProgressView is not updated. In other languages there is a view update command that you have to execute in these circumstances. What is the Cocoa equivalent or do you have to effect some other workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the UI is only updated periodically as the run (event) loop turns.  A `for()` loop, which I am assuming runs on the main thread, is going to block the run loop until finished.  Not only does this mean the progress bar won't be updated (or, rather, will jump right to 100% at the end), but that you are potentially going to freeze the UI for some time.  (I assume, since you are showing a progress bar, that this could take a while.)

What you want to do, for any lengthy operation, is to have the work done on a separate queue/thread, and call out the update the UI on the main thread periodically.  For example, you might try something like (**warning: typed in browser**):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    int j = 1000;
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
        // Do your presumably useful work, not just looping for fun :-)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // UI updates always come from the main queue!
            calculatingProgressBar.progress = (i/j);
        });
    }
});
```

This example uses GCD ([Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)).  There are higher level constructs you can also look at, like [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html), but the basic idea remains the same.

If you are unfamiliar with concurrent (multithreaded) programming, you are going to have a modest learning curve to get up to speed.  I suggest starting with the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Were does this code need to go. I naively (?) put it in my (IBAction) section and it appears to not trigger in any way. The code compiles but nothing happens when the button is triggered...

Comment: Is the code actually called? Try putting a breakpoint inside each of the dispatch_async calls.

Answer (score 1):

The UI can't update itself while you're running code on the main thread. This is intentional and greatly improves performance. That means that no updates happen to the UI until `start` returns. You're updating `progress` many times, and then returning, so it's drawn once.

You will need to use a timer or a GCD queue to achieve what you're talking about. It depends quite a bit on what the rest of your code looks like, but here's one approach, if you wanted it to run over 60 seconds for instance:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender{
  calculatingProgressBar.progress = 0.0;  
  int j = 60;

  dispatch_time_t now = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
  for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(now, i * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_current_queue(),
                   ^{
                     calculatingProgressBar.progress = (i/j);
                    });
    }
}
```

What this does is set up 60 events and schedules them to run one second apart. It then returns (without running them yet).

There are lots of other approaches, such as `NSTimer` or GCD timers. You can also move your processing to a background thread with `dispatch_async()`. (see Conrad Shultz's answer for that)

Comment: I had read around this topic and presume you had to trip and trick the UI to update. When I try this code I get a message:

Initializing 'const struct timespec'  with an expression of incompatible type int.

Comment: Message removed - double posted

Comment: edited. There's no trickery required. You just need to behave asynchronously as the system expects.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant (and versatile) solution is this:
In your delegate, have this this:

```
maxNumber = 1000; // define this somewhere, just for convenience
...
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doLoop:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxNumber]];
```

Have a method like this:

```
- (void)doLoop:(NSNumber *)myMaxNumber { // this runs on the background
  calculatingProgressBar.progress = 0.0;  
  NSNumber *j = myMaxNumber;
  for (int i=0; i<j; i++) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
  // here you could call a method in the main thread, just to signify that your loop is done.
  // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loopDone:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

and the update is done here:

```
-(void)updateProgress:(NSNumber *)myNumber {
  calculatingProgressBar.progress = ([myNumber intValue]/maxNumber);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that calculatingProgressBar is an IBOutlet then you probably just need to set the new value in a KVO compliant way, that is use the setter:  self.calculatingProgressBar.progress = (i/j);

Comment: As you have probably gathered I'm in post virgin mode with Xcode. I'm eager to do more but there's a lot of fumbling going on.

I suspect I've been given three excellent steers of advice but have not yet got the nous yet to shoehorn them to work.

prefixing self. into the line gives a message

Property 'calculatingProgressBar' not found on object of type 'VC name...

Comment: XCode is not your issue. Cocoa is. :)

Comment: @EdwardHasted -- You got that error message because you haven't declared calculatingProgressBar as a property. I was wrong about the "self" thing though - you don't need that. The other answers here point out one of the main problems with your code though.  But one that everybody missed so far is you can't declare i and j as ints, because doing so will cause i/j to always equal 0 (because you're doing integer math, so any fractions go to 0).  If you declare them as floats (or doubles) you should see the bar jump immediately to 100%, because of the run loop problem mentioned by Conrad Shultz

Comment: Can I thank all three of you for your time, patience and advice. I have now got this to work as a result and am beginning to understand the solution. It will take time it to really sink in.

Not having the calculatingProgressBar defined as a property was critical. 

Very many thanks, Ed